# Doctrine always return null values in production

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2, and I don't know why, currently if I'm in production environment, when I create a new field in one of my tables I always return null value with get.

If I use:

```
console doctrine:schema:validate
```

I get that all it's ok.

I always creat tables using:

```
console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But if for example I do:

```
$test = $entity->getTest();
```

In production always I get NULL, but in Develpment environment, I get the correct value.

My database mapping it's so big, for this puropose I can't write here.

Somebody have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? **edit**: have you cleared Symfony/APC cache after update?

Comment: Different Doctrine config for dev and prod environments?

Comment: Thanks, Symfony cache is cleared, and I haven't any error in log. How can I clear APC cache? And my configuration it's the same in both environments. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the problem was APC cache. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hi: how did you cleared APC cache?

Comment: @OscarPérez the easiest way is to restart `apache`. You can also execute `php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"`

Comment: in my case the command "apc_clear_..." did not work, I had to restart FPM. (/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart) Thanks @bartek

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear Symfony/APC cache using those command :

```
 sudo php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata  --env=prod
 sudo php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  --env=prod
 sudo php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod
```